# Select consecultive times in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a data frame where I would like to select the consecutive timestamp. I mean times that happen one after the other, in this case, that happened 15 minutes consecutively. 
For example,

```
2017-07-19 17:45:00+02:00    16
2017-07-23 02:45:00+02:00    23
2017-07-25 14:15:00+02:00    23
2017-07-27 07:00:00+02:00    25
2017-07-28 09:30:00+02:00    22
2017-07-28 18:00:00+02:00    17
2017-07-29 04:00:00+02:00    28
2017-07-29 04:15:00+02:00    19
2017-07-29 11:30:00+02:00    20
2017-07-30 09:00:00+02:00    11
2017-08-03 02:45:00+02:00    22
2017-08-04 06:45:00+02:00    27
2017-08-06 01:45:00+02:00    21
2017-08-08 19:30:00+02:00    27
2017-08-08 19:45:00+02:00    27
2017-08-08 20:00:00+02:00    15
2017-08-08 21:45:00+02:00    25
```

I would select only those from the above dataframe

```
2017-07-29 04:00:00+02:00    28
2017-07-29 04:15:00+02:00    19
2017-08-08 19:30:00+02:00    27
2017-08-08 19:45:00+02:00    27
2017-08-08 20:00:00+02:00    15
```

I have This is just an example but I am dealing with many timestamps. How can I do this with python commands?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "consecutive timestamps"?

Comment: Okay, based on your edit, how would this generalise to your actual problem? For example, do you want to select all rows within a 15 minute interval, or all consecutive rows within the same hour, or just those rows for 4:XXPM? It isn't clear still.

Comment: @Mayra can you be more specific. You mean consecutive hours?

Comment: My data happens every 15 minutes so consecutive times are the ones that continue to happen every 15 minutes In this order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could

```
In [202]: s = df.time.diff().dt.total_seconds().eq(900)

In [203]: df[s.shift(-1) | s]
Out[203]:
                  time   v
6  2017-07-29 02:00:00  28
7  2017-07-29 02:15:00  19
13 2017-08-08 17:30:00  27
14 2017-08-08 17:45:00  27
15 2017-08-08 18:00:00  15
```

---

```
In [205]: df.time.diff().dt.total_seconds().eq(900)
Out[205]:
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7      True
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
13    False
14     True
15     True
16    False
Name: time, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you! df is the dataframe and what is dt, in this case?